# Run method async with cancel support

Tags: c#, async-await, task, cancellation

I have to call a method from an external library. I have no control over it and it blocks the UI for 5 secounds+. It is just one method. Because I really like async/await, my code looks like that:

```
SoundSource = await Task.Run(() => CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(Path));
```

The problem is that it can last about 30 secounds and the user wants to cancel it. My first thought: Set in the `GetAwaiter().OnCompleted` an AutoResetEvent and run a `while` which waits 500 ms for the AutoResetEvent and than checks, if a bool variable `_cancelLoading` is true:

```
            using (var waithandler = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            {
                var x = track.GetSoundSource();
                x.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { waithandler.Set(); });
                while (!x.IsCompleted)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => waithandler.WaitOne(500));
                    if (_cancelLoading)
                    {
                        x.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => x.Result.Dispose());
                        _isLoadingSoundSource = false;
                        _cancelLoading = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                _isLoadingSoundSource = false;
                SoundSource = x.Result;
            }
```

But that is not a good solution because it doesn't know if it can set `_isLoadingSoundSource` to true because the new method could be still running the procedure. It could be fixed with another, global AutoResetEvent, but that's really complicated and can end in easily end in a dead look.

Is there a good way to "cancel" the method/Task (i don't have to use tasks if they don't support that). I don't need to abort it, it would be nice if it can run until it ends and than just dispose the result.

Comment: Have you looked into the TPL's cancellation support at all?  The documentation is *filled* with information on how to cancel tasks.

Comment: Yes, sure, but that only works if you control the task.

Comment: It can only prevent the operation from continuing to execute if that operation was built to support cooprative cancellation.  You can trivially mark the task as completed before the operation has actually finished without that support though, which is exactly what you're trying to do, and something that the TPL can most certainly handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot cancel the actual operation (`GetCodec`), then all you can do is *ignore the results* when a cancellation is requested:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
async Task SetSoundSourceAsync(string path)
{
  if (_cts != null)
    _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var token = _cts.Token;
  var result = await Task.Run(() => CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(path));
  if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    return;
  SoundSource = result;
}
```

The example code above assumes it is called from a UI thread. If it's not, there would be a race condition on `_cts`.